# SDWebImage crash my app with "Terminating since there is no system app"

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, sdwebimage

I use SDWebImage api to download image from server.

The code as following:

```
[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourceInfo.previewImageUrl]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image"]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                             [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        }];
```

I use UITableView or UICollectionView to display the image.My image resource is big(more than 2MB).I monitor the memory usage, is not growing fast.

I use the simulator and the code work well,no memory warning.

But when I deploy my project to the iPad(iOS 8.1), my app crashes every time (when show the image table view) and my iPad displays a black screen with the white apple logo. Like the boot up screen but only for a few seconds. Then the iPad goes back to the locked screen.

The log windows says : "Terminating since there is no system app".Sometimes also display memory warning info.Sometimes cause signal SIGTERM.

I have add "All Exceptions" breakpoint, but never called.

I also add SDImageCache clear memory method in didReceiveMemoryWarning

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];
}
```

Comment: Not enough info. iPad can't handle images that are around 4000x6000 px (standard resolution on semi-pro and pro cameras nowadays) if you don't optimise for them.

Comment: My image has 4000*3000 resolution.Every picture's size over 2MB.

Comment: Yep, then definitely check out [DFImageManager 0.7.1](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager). It now decompresses and scales images in a single step (x2-4 times faster depending on scale, significantly reduces memory usage) which allows it to scale large images (~6000x4000 px) and prepare them for display with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue already. I only use SDWebImageDownloader to download the image.Then save the image to special location by myself.Then generate one shortcut image(compress & resize) for the origin image,I use the compressed image in UIImageView, it works well.So it's because the origin image data is too big.

```
UIImage *localImage = [[ImageResourceManager sharedInstance] getShortcutImage:currentResourceInfo.previewImageUrl];
if (localImage != nil) {
    cell.previewImageView.image = localImage;
}
else
{
    [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentResourceInfo.previewImageUrl]
                                                        options:0
                                                       progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                                                       }
                                                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                                                          if (image && finished) {
                                                              [[ImageResourceManager sharedInstance] storeImageToLocal:image
                                                                                                              imageUrl:currentResourceInfo.previewImageUrl];
                                                              if (self.viewModel.currentSelectResourceType == Picture) {
                                                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                      cell.previewImageView.image = [[ImageResourceManager sharedInstance] getShortcutImage:currentResourceInfo.previewImageUrl];
                                                                  });
                                                              }
                                                          }
                                                          [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                                      }];
}
```

Comment: You may try [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) next time, it does resizing for you :)